# Lua - Overloading of Comparison Operators

Tags: lua

I was just wondering if there is any future plan for Lua to allow users to return `userdata` type when overloading comparison operators, such as >, <, ==. Currently, all comparison operators defaults to `boolean` type and in my opinion this prevents many shortcut expressions especially when trying to design code for scientific purposes, such as `matrix1<matrix2` and you want to return a matrix.

It is possible to overcome this by designing `matrix3=matrix1:less(matrix2)`; however, many engineers and scientists dont enjoy this type of syntax and prefer the simple way: `matrix3=matrix1<matrix2`.

C++ allows and as I know Python allows this kind of flexibility. I was just wondering whether this is how not Lua has been designed from the very beginning or it was just for some reason a preference and therefore in the future versions it is possible for Lua to allow this flexibility.

Comment: Currently, there are no plans for that. But the question is off topic here.

Comment: @macroland: "*such as matrix1<matrix2 and you want to return a matrix*" ... why would you *want* that to return a matrix? What would that matrix mean, and how would you use the matrix to do actual comparisons? What "scientific purposes" are you talking about where this is sort of thing is expected?

Comment: @lhf: thanks for the info and sorry if the topic is not suitable for here.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Say you have an array of numbers a=[1 5 10 2] and you would like to return another array meeting the certain conditions such as a<5 to return [1 2]. Languages such as R and Matlab has syntax support for this type of comparisons. I know for Lua this would not language-wise satisfy the expression `if(matrix1<matrix2)` and if such is used by the programmer compiler can throw error, probably this is not hard to detect that it is a userdata whereas expected is boolean. I was just curious if Lua had a plan to allow comparison operators to return a type other than boolean.

Comment: Excellent question. Although you should have given R code as an example instead of the matrix.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not lua author, but can guarantee that >, < and == in lua will return boolean even in future.
As you have mentioned, C++ and Python allows this. Python is close to C++ as Lua is close to C, I mean some kind of philosophy. So for those who like C++ described thing is lack of feature in Lua, while for C programmers it is the freaking part of OOP languages.

Just imaging that someone will read your program :)

```
matrix3 = matrix1 < matrix2
```

What? `<` operator builds matrix instead of comparison?

```
matrix3 = m1 > m2
matrix3 = m1 == m1
matrix3 = m1 ~= m2
```

If language supports such things just kill it with fire (as of C philosophy point)

Lua is the only one I know scripting language with *perfect* designed abstractions, I mean, though Lua has metatables and metamethods, programmer still can read code and understand what is going on here.

My point is that well designed language must rescue programmers from themselves.

Comment: It should be noted that C++'s new `<=>` doesn't take well to these kind of shenanigans either. While `operator<=>` can be made to return anything, if you don't return one of the proper values, then the system cannot generate the other comparison operators based on that.